# Adding TOC Hyperlinks with multiple valid references available

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently looking to expand the functionality of an existing macro-enabled workbook by adding hyperlinks to an existing "Contents" sheet. The workbook operates much like a dashboard: button commands on the "Contents" sheet activate macros that pull templates from a remote source, change the sheet name to be unique while identifying with the location being added, copy them to the local workbook, and update the bottom of the location list on the contents sheet with the location added.

The problem arises when I have locations with several iterations of the same calculations between the locations, and up to 30 sheets in the same workbook. It takes time for the end-user to click through all the tabs to find the specific calculation required for the specific location. So, what I had hoped to do would be to create a hyperlink on the contents page linking to the first calculation related to the location in question.

For example, *Location A* has 3 different calculations associated with it, while *Location B* has 4. How would I identify which sheet contains the first calculation for the associated location?

My thoughts: I have a sort code **(EDIT: see below)** implemented upon adding a new location where it sorts the contents sheet then iterates through the entire workbook, grouping sheets named *Location X (Calc n)* and pushing the group of worksheets to the back of the workbook based on the new order on the contents sheet. I'm thinking this would be the ideal spot to insert the hyperlink, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Perhaps declaring and assigning a string variable the value of the currently selected location, making a logical comparison and counting the number of sheets assigned to said location, resetting the counter when the location name changes, and using the active sheet in the hyperlink anchor when the counter equals 0?

**EDIT :**

```
Dim Group_Sheets As Worksheet
Dim wSheet As Variant
Dim SortRng, rng As Range

Set SortRng = Range(Range("A6"), Range("A6").End(xlDown))
For Each rng In SortRng
    ReDim wSheet(0)
    For Each Group_Sheets In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(Group_Sheets.Name, Len(rng)) = rng Then
            wSheet(UBound(wSheet)) = Group_Sheets.Name
            ReDim Preserve wSheet(UBound(wSheet) + 1)
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve wSheet(UBound(wSheet) - 1)
    With Worksheets(wSheet)
        .Select
        .Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End With
Next
```

Comment: So I made a temporary workaround by adding a hyperlink whose address is the final sheet copied from templates when adding a location. This is far from ideal, however, because it will not have the ability to update the hyperlink should the end user delete the calculation that is linked. After seeing the results of this, I believe using the last sheet would be acceptable as well. It feels like the answer is staring me in the face... I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the hyperlink when the group of sheets are moved has resolved the issue.

```
Set SortRng = Range(Range("A6"), Range("A6").End(xlDown))
For Each rng In SortRng
    ReDim wSheet(0)
    For Each Group_Sheets In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(Group_Sheets.Name, Len(rng)) = rng Then
            wSheet(UBound(wSheet)) = Group_Sheets.Name
            ReDim Preserve wSheet(UBound(wSheet) + 1)
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve wSheet(UBound(wSheet) - 1)
    With Worksheets(wSheet)
        .Select
        .Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End With
'Select the sheet to which the hyperlink directs HERE
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
'Insert hyperlink HERE
    TOC_Sheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng.Offset(0, 1), _
        Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!A1", _
        ScreenTip:=ActiveSheet.Name, _
        TextToDisplay:="Link"
Next
```